# Error using pymodis.convertmodis.createMosaic

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcpy, pymodis

I am using pymodis to reproject and mosaic the datasets using MRT. I have successfully reprojected the data using pymodis package as below :

```
list_modis=glob.glob('*.hdf')

for i in range(0,len(list_modis)):
     name=parameter_file(INPUT_folder,list_modis[i],left_x,right_x,top_y,bottom_y)
     x=pymodis.convertmodis.convertModis(list_modis[i],'param.prm','C:\\MRT\\')
     x.run()
```

This works perfectly well, but when I am using Create Mosaic I got problem. Please suggest me where I have made mistake.

```
y=pymodis.convertmodis.createMosaic('mosaicinput.txt','mosaic','C:\\MRT\\')
y.run()
```

Mosaicinput.txt has following files:

MOD15A2.A2001025.h27v08.005.2006356072429.hdf MOD15A2.A2001025.h27v09.005.2006356181328.hdf MOD15A2.A2001025.h28v08.005.2006356073508.hdf MOD15A2.A2001025.h28v09.005.2006356075256.hdf

When I run this code, I got the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jaya_HOME\Desktop\WEB DHM Toolbox\script\modis_mosaic.py", line 125, in 
    y.run()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\pymodis\convertmodis.py", line 177, in run
    self.write_mosaic_xml()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\pymodis\convertmodis.py", line 156, in write_mosaic_xml
    pmm = parseModisMulti(listHDF)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\pymodis\parsemodis.py", line 555, in __init__
    self.parModis.append(parseModis(i))
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\pymodis\parsemodis.py", line 64, in __init__
    raise IOError('{name} does not exist'.format(name=filename))
IOError: MOD15A2.A2001025.h27v08.005.2006356072429.hdf MOD15A2.A2001025.h27v09.005.2006356181328.hdf MOD15A2.A2001025.h28v08.005.2006356073508.hdf MOD15A2.A2001025.h28v09.005.2006356075256.hdf does not exist
```

This is the syntax of this module :

```
class pymodis.convertmodis.createMosaic(listfile, outprefix, mrtpath, subset=False)[source]
A class to convert several MODIS tiles into a mosaic

Parameters: 
listfile (str) – the path to file with the list of HDF MODIS file
outprefix (str) – the prefix for output files
mrtpath (str) – the full path to mrt directory which contains the bin and data directories
subset (str) – a string composed by 1 and 0 according with the layer to mosaic. The string should something like ‘1 0 1 0 0 0 0’
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have been trying to run the  modis_mosaic.py python script that I believe does the same job you are trying here. I got the same error that "blahblah.hdf file doesnot exist". Here is the remedy that I found :

So the script has been given a path to the text file but it doesn't realize that the .hdf files are to be searched in that directory itself and instead it searches for the files in the pymodis/scripts directory. I can say so because after I copied the .hdf files into the pymodis/scripts folder and then tried executing the command it worked perfectly.\

I think this is because of the nature of python, where it searches for the files always in it's current directory unless otherwise explicitly specified like we specified the .txt file

Hope it makes sense

Comment: I am sorry, the thing is that the .hdf files have to be in the same directory from wherein your are running the commands. So try changing to the directory that consists the .hdf files and then run the command.                                                                                                  It need not necessarily be the pymodis/scripts directory like I mentioned before